# Why does LogisticAggregator (Spark mllib.ml) not use z-score normalization?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I find LogisticAggregator in Spark.mllib.ml package standardizes feature values by this code : (value / featuresStd(index). It is very similar to  z-score normalization. I wonder that Why LogisticAggregator (Spark mllib.ml) not use z-score normalization ?

```
val margin = - {
        var sum = 0.0
        features.foreachActive { (index, value) =>
          if (featuresStd(index) != 0.0 && value != 0.0) {
            sum += localCoefficientsArray(index) * (value / featuresStd(index))
          }
        }
        sum + {
          if (fitIntercept) localCoefficientsArray(dim) else 0.0
        }
      }

      val multiplier = weight * (1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(margin)) - label)
```

Comment: class definition： private class LogisticAggregator(
    coefficients: Vector,
    numClasses: Int,
    fitIntercept: Boolean,
    featuresStd: Array[Double],
    featuresMean: Array[Double]) extends Serializable